# This if statement is not even working correctly

Tags: python, string

```
if string in secret_word:
    print("Good!")
else:
    print("Bad...")
```

I'm trying to check if a letter is a word like this:

---

if A is in the word Apple then it will return Good! But if it is not, it will return Bad...

It also says that it is a TypeError and not an indentation error.

Comment: There is something called python `indentation`.

Comment: Fix your indentation please. Also, I think this goes without saying, but it isn't easy to pinpoint the problem without seeing more of your code to understand how these variables are initialised. You can do that much, yes?

Comment: case matters as well

Comment: Would recommend checking out how if statements work in python as the problem is pretty basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with your indentation. You can learn about indentation here: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html and on the web. To get your code working do the following:

```
string = "A"
secret_word = "Apple"

if string in secret_word:
    print("Good!")
else:
    print("Bad...")
```

Comment: We don't actually know if the indentation is wrong in the original code or if this is a typo when copy-pasting here...

Comment: Well the indentation is definitely wrong, could be a copy paste error for sure, i'm sure the OP will enlighten us. Its a thrilling question ;-)

Comment: Well it is saying “TypeError: argument of type ‘int’ is not iterable”.

Comment: Hahaha, ok, we you need to update your question, and show how you are constructing the variables string, and secret_word. Clearly your secret word is a number not a python string.